# Change zeros into their closest left nonzero neighbors in an array

Tags: python

Assuming I have an array :

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
```

How can I change the zeros into the value of its closest left non-zero neighbor?

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Hello, Ginna. What have you tried so far? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What should happen if the array starts with zero (0)?

Answer (score 1):

```
l=[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
arr=[]
for i in l:
    if i!=0:
        arr.append(i)
        left_element=i 
    else:
        arr.append(left_element)
print(arr)
```

keep track of non zero left element and append it to the new list
Space:-O(n)
runtime:-O(n)

OR

```
l=[1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i]!=0:
        left_element=l[i]
    else:
        l[i]=left_element
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through your array and evaluate each item, replacing when necessary:

```
arr = [1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]

# replace values with the following
previous_x = None
for i,x in enumerate(arr):
    if x>0:
        previous_x = x
    else:
        arr[i] = previous_x
```

If your array is massive (>100,000), I would look into leveraging numpy for a solution.